Got stuck with this new topic to prove the following inequality.
I know basic identities only. One of my friend's wards is having difficulty in proving the following. Please let me know some directions or hints.

Prove that if $a,b,c$ are real numbers, then $(3abc-a^3-b^3-c^3) ^2 \leq (a^2+b^2+c^2) ^3$.

I have tried on my own as follows:
$$((a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca))^2 < ((a+b+c)^2-2(ab+bc+ca))^3.$$
And now I am stuck.

I don't know why this question (and also my answer) was downvoted.

Let us denote $P = a^2 + b^2 +c^2$ and $Q = ab+bc+ca$
As you already proved
$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc = (a+b+c)(a^2+b^2 +c^2 -ab-bc-ca)$$
then
$$\begin{align}
\text{LHS}-\text{RHS} &= (a+b+c)^2(P-Q)^2 -P^3\\
&=(P+2Q)(P-Q)^2-P^3\\
&=-3Q^2P+2Q^3\\
&=Q^2(-3P+2Q)\\
\text{LHS}-\text{RHS}&=(ab+bc+ca)^2(-a^2-b^2-c^2 -(a-b)^2 -(b-c)^2-(c-a)^2)\le0
\end{align}$$
The equality occurs iff $a=b=c=0$.
